# Error entering information

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I'm continuing to receive an error working on a program for my C class. I'm currently a student learning so any help would be useful.
There Current program that I am working on requires us to out put a grade report, but I'm receiving errors entering information. When I am prompted to enter info my I keep getting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ordXV.png  [1]
I'm unsure how to fix it. I was told it had something to do with the memory storage. I've tried googling and haven't received any help. Here is my code:

```
include <stdio.h>
include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) { char Name[40]; char cid1[6]="", cid2[6]="", cid3[6]="", cid4[6]="", 
cid5[6]="", cid6[6]=""; 

char Description1[21]="", Description2[21]="", Description3[21]="",Description4[21]="", Description5[21]="", Description6[21]=""; 
int hrs1 = 0, hrs2=0, hrs3=0, hrs4=0, hrs5=0, hrs6=0, GPA=0, TotalHrs=0, TotalPoints=0;        char grade1[2]="",grade2[2]="",grade3[2]="",grade4[2]="",grade5[2]="",grade6[2]="";

printf("Enter Students Name ");
fgets(Name, 20, stdin);

printf("Enter Class ID ");
fgets(cid1, 6, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter Class Description ");
fgets(Description1, 20, stdin);
printf("Enter Class Hours ");
scanf("%d", &hrs1);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter Class Grade ");
scanf("%c", &grade1);


printf("Enter Second Class ID ");
fgets(cid2, 6, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter Class Description ");
fgets(Description2, 20, stdin);
printf("Enter Class Hours ");
scanf("%d", &hrs2);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter Class Grade ");
scanf("%c", &grade2);


printf("Enter Third Class ID ");
fgets(cid3, 6, stdin);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter Class Description ");
fgets(Description3, 20, stdin);
printf("Enter Class Hours ");
scanf("%d", &hrs3);
fflush(stdin);
printf("Enter Class Grade ");
scanf("%c", &grade3);


TotalHrs = (hrs1 + hrs2+hrs3+hrs4+hrs5+hrs6);
if  (TotalHrs > 24)
printf("You're taking too many classes");
else if (TotalHrs < 1) 
printf("You're not taking enough classes! Enroll in more!");

printf("%d", TotalHrs);

system("pause");

return 0; }
```

The program isn't complete so any help would be wonderful! Tips on shortening or anything is welcomed.

Comment: I don't understand what the error is.

Comment: This keeps happning :http://i.imgur.com/YuiNI88.png?1 not allowing me to enter my information needed

Comment: How do these char array initializations work?